# Forward Vector in Blender (python)

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

How to determine forward vector in the blender? I mean similar to transform.forward in Unity game engine. Could anyone provide guidance? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Forward needs a reference to make sense. Forward to what? Can you specify? Looking at tags: python + blender-render lefts me confused too..

Comment: @Jaroslav Jerryno Novotny: thank you for the response forward meaning the direction the object that is facing local z axis or local y-axis like that

Answer (score 1):

To express some object's local y axis in world coordinates you just multiply a (0,1,0) vector with the object's world matrix:

```
import bpy
form mathutils import Vector

ob = bpy.context.scene.objects.get("Object")
forward = ob.matrix_world * Vector((0,1,0))
```

If the object has scale and you need a vector with unit length, you also need to normalize the result.